# How to loop a nested array in C

Tags: arrays, c

I've been developing a guessing game in which the goal is to guess the character selected by the user among specific characters, anyway, my first and only idea is to create an array with the questions to be asked, and each question has its options like in the code below I'm a newbie in C language so that I there are several things which I'm not sure how to handle. In short, I'd like to know how can I loop over the array showing to the user the questions with its questions to be answered? Here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
    
#define ROW 500
#define LINE 200
    
//Read file and append to an array buffer
char *characters(){
    
    char *source = NULL;
    
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    
    if (fp != NULL) {
        /* Go to the end of the file. */
        if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END) == 0) {
            /* Get the size of the file. */
            long bufsize = ftell(fp);
    
            if (bufsize == -1) { /* Error */ }
    
            /* Allocate our buffer to that size. */
            source = malloc(sizeof(char) * (bufsize + 1));
    
            /* Go back to the start of the file. */
            if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET) != 0) { /* Error */ }
    
            /* Read the entire file into memory. */
            size_t newLen = fread(source, sizeof(char), bufsize, fp);
            if ( ferror( fp ) != 0 ) {
                fputs("Error reading file", stderr);
            } else {
                source[newLen++] = '\0'; /* Just to be safe. */
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    
    return source;
}
    
    
char *strndup(const char *s, size_t n) {
    char *p;
    size_t n1;
    
    for (n1 = 0; n1 < n && s[n1] != '\0'; n1++)
        continue;
    p = malloc(n + 1);
    if (p != NULL) {
        memcpy(p, s, n1);
        p[n1] = '\0';
    }
    return p;
}
    
// User input
char *input(){
    char *value;
    char buffer[10];
    int j = 0;
    
    while( j < 1 && fgets(buffer, 10, stdin) != NULL){
        value = strndup(buffer, 10);
        j++;
    }
    return value;
}
    
// Main function
int main (void)
{
    char *questions[] = {
        "Genre",{"male","female"},
        "Hair", {"black","red","blond"},
        "Cloths",{"dress","shirt","pants"},
        "pet", {"dog","cat","pig"}
    };
    
    int asked[4] = {0};
    char *answers[5];
    char buffer[6];
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int q = rand() % 4;
    
        while (asked[q])
            q = rand() % 4;
        asked[q]++;
    
        printf ("%s\n", questions[q]);
    
        answers[i] = input();
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf(" %s ",answers[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That's the file's structure I'll compare as long as I have all the answers from the user.

```
female,blond,vestido,pig,character b
male,black,shirt,pants,dog,character c
male,black,shirt,pants,cat,character d
female,blond,dress,cat,character A
male,red,shirt,pants,pig,character e
```

Comment: Not sure how this weighs into the big-picture problem, but your `input()` function can return garbage (an uninitialized `value` variable) in some cases, and it will repeatedly leak memory in the `while` loop, keeping only the last allocated `value`.

Comment: Also worth compiling your code with max warnings; it's pointing out quite a few issues, especially with the organization of the `questions` array, which feels like it's going to be part of your real issues.

Comment: I've been searching for a good structure to store the questions and options on the internet and I came across structures, Do you think It would be good to change the array to structures? @Steve Friedl

Comment: Structures that would allow you to group topics and answers together sounds like a fine idea, but it's going to be a little tricky to get right due to possibly variable-length answers. Probably will need to create individual structure variables, then a single array of pointer-to-structure to group them all together.

Comment: ... but before you do anything with structures, be sure you understand what's wrong with the current array of questions; the code seems to think there's four of something, but there's not.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice @Steve Friedl